# Assigning different IP from range on dnsmasq DHCP server

Tags: linux, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have an installed dnsmasq DHCP server. I want to assign different IP address from defined range. For instance my IP range is 10.11.12.10 - 10.11.12.50 but I want to assign different IP (192.168.1.15) for specific MAC address. Is this possible?

I try to lease but it doesn't work. Sample configuration file:

```
strict-order
user=libvirt-dnsmasq
pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/guest.pid
except-interface=lo
interface=br0
dhcp-option=3
no-resolv
dhcp-range=10.11.12.10,10.11.12.50
dhcp-no-override
dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/guest.leases
dhcp-lease-max=6
```

Answer (score 1):

You would like to set up a DHCP reservation.

This can be done by placing the MAC address and the desired IP address in /etc/ethers. This will be acknowledged by DNSMASQ.

You would not be able to assign the 192.168.1.15 address as it is outside your subnet.